# Trying to display variable value in confirm message: Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, variables, message, confirmation

I am trying to create a validation for a list of radio buttons, which, if successful, prompts a confirm box. The confirm box must state which button the user has selected, and then allow them to confirm.

The validation works, but when the popup box appears, I can't get the user's selection to display in the message, either by using checked or checked.value. Here's the code:

```
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('levels');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       checked = inputs[i];
       break;
   }
}

if(checked==null)
{

alert('Please choose an exam level.');
return false;
}

else {
return confirm('You have chosen '+ checked + ', is this correct?');
}
```

Using this code, the message displayed is "You have chosen [object HTMLInputElement], is this correct?", regardless of which button is selected.

How do I correctly refer to the variable to avoid this?

Comment: You probably want `checked = inputs[i].value`. `inputs[i]` is the DOM Element, when cast to a string it becomes `"[object HTMLInputElement]"` (in case of an input element).

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cm57yj73/.  You should post your comment as an answer, @Halcyon or the question should be marked for close as an Off-Topic->a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `checked = inputs[i].value`. `inputs[i]` is the DOM Element, when cast to a string it becomes `"[object HTMLInputElement]"` (in case of an input element).